# Create object in model having foreigkey relation

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create an entry in this `Something model` in python manage.py shell using this
`Someting.objects.create(discussion_title="General", user_username="admin", content="Hello")`

models example

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False,)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, )


class Something(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(Discussion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(unique=False, blank=False)
```

I am getting this error
`TypeError: Something() got an unexpected keyword argument 'discussion_title'`

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to use double under bar `__` to use django's model relation expression.

```py
Someting.objects.get(discussion__title="General", user__username="admin", content="Hello")
```

Second, you can't use double under bar relation expression when create an object.
if you want to create an object in relation, you have to create in step by step. follow @Nicolas Appriou 's answer

Answer (score 0):

Your *Something* model does not have a *discussion_title* field. You need to create a *Discussion* instance for this.

This model does not have a *user_username* model either.

```
discussion = Discussion.objects.create(title="Foobar")
discussion.users.add(User.objects.create(username="Ham")
Something.objects.create(
    discussion=discussion,
)
```

Comment: Can you explain it more or direct me to some docs? Like let's say `title = "Foobar" `already exist in Discussion model and I have a user with `username = "Ham"` . Will this work?

Comment: This is the basics of database access in django. I can only give you a link to the model documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#relationships